# Master-detail view using a found set

Tags: filemaker

I have two tables: `Users` and `Tasks`. Each `User` can have many `Tasks` but every `Task` can have only one `User`.

If I click on John Smith in the first layout I'll be taken to a new layout that shows me only John's tasks (thanks to "Go to related record" script).

Now, what I'm trying to accomplish - and need some help with - is from this layout I would like to be able to see a scrolling list of all John's tasks on the left (but only their titles). When I select, say, Task 20 I want to see all of Task 20's metadata on the right. In other words, a master-detail view like this:

[image]

I followed this [video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/164338472)​ which got me close to my goal but not all the way. If you skip to the 6:20 mark you can see what he does. But basically his approach is this:

- From the Contacts layout he creates a portal.
- He creates a summary field called listOf and chooses to create a "List of" IDs from the Contacts table
- He creates a relationship from the ID field and the listOf field
- He populates the portal with this data
- He uses a script to "Go to related record" when the user clicks on a button in the row

This approach works great for the master-detail view, but it has one problem for me. I don't want to see all tasks, just John's tasks (or whoever I clicked on in the previous layout).

Not sure how to solve this. Do I need to create a "Constrained found set" when I navigate from John Smith's record in the previous Users layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would have a standard portal on the left, using a cartesian join to show all records, or you can use this technique with the summary field if you wish, but it is not necessary.

Then add a filter to the portal to only display records with the same User ID as the current record. This will accomplish what you need.

Comment: What is a cartesian join? is it the "X" join type?

Comment: And how do you filter by current record?

Comment: Yes, an x join. Filter like this: User::UserID = Task::UserID. With your own Id fields.

Comment: Got it. And if I were to be using a join table for `Users` and `Tasks` called `UsersTasks` how would I filter?

Comment: And relatedly, should my layout be based on the join table `UserTasks` or the records themselves, `Tasks`?

Comment: Layout should be based on the Task table as before. Change the portal to UsersTasks table. Change the Task table in the filter to the Usertasks table.

Comment: Yes, you need a cartesian join with portal filter  if you don’t want to specify the filter criteria directly as a match in a new relationship. A new relationship is good to keep the regular one unchanged.

Comment: The problem I can't seem to fix is that the data displayed in the portal rows is repeating itself. It's all based on the currently selected record in the layout form view, not showing me all of the unique instances of `tasks`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159533/discussion-between-colindunn-and-andreast).